# Get most recent flagged record

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.7

I have the following MySQL (v5.7) table:

| ID | PersonID | Featured | CreatedAt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1743455 | 54924 | 0 | 2021-10-21 12:15:54 |
| 1743460 | 54924 | 1 | 2021-10-21 12:30:38 |
| 1743465 | 54924 | 0 | 2021-10-21 12:52:05 |
| 1743467 | 54924 | 0 | 2021-10-21 12:54:58 |
| 1743471 | 54924 | 0 | 2021-10-21 13:10:22 |
| 1743472 | 54924 | 1 | 2021-10-21 13:23:27 |
| 1743473 | 54924 | 0 | 2021-10-21 13:42:00 |
| 1743474 | 54924 | 0 | 2021-10-21 13:43:50 |
| 1743475 | 54924 | 0 | 2021-10-21 13:47:08 |
| 1743476 | 54924 | 0 | 2021-10-21 13:48:36 |
| 1743484 | 54924 | 1 | 2021-10-21 16:31:03 |

Id like to have a query that creates a column flagging the most recent feature photo

Expected Result:

| ID | PersonID | Featured | CreatedAt | MostRecentFeatured |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1743455 | 54924 | 0 | 2021-10-21 12:15:54 | 0 |
| 1743460 | 54924 | 1 | 2021-10-21 12:30:38 | 0 |
| 1743465 | 54924 | 0 | 2021-10-21 12:52:05 | 0 |
| 1743467 | 54924 | 0 | 2021-10-21 12:54:58 | 0 |
| 1743471 | 54924 | 0 | 2021-10-21 13:10:22 | 0 |
| 1743472 | 54924 | 1 | 2021-10-21 13:23:27 | 0 |
| 1743473 | 54924 | 0 | 2021-10-21 13:42:00 | 0 |
| 1743474 | 54924 | 0 | 2021-10-21 13:43:50 | 0 |
| 1743475 | 54924 | 0 | 2021-10-21 13:47:08 | 0 |
| 1743476 | 54924 | 0 | 2021-10-21 13:48:36 | 0 |
| 1743484 | 54924 | 1 | 2021-10-21 16:31:03 | 1 |

How can I do this?

I tried to do with a subquery but it slowed down my query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in mysql 8+ :

```
select * , case when row_number() over (partition by PersonId order by CreatedAt desc) = 1 then 1 else 0 end as MostRecentFeatured
from table1
```

in older mysql :

```
select a.*, case when b.personId is not null then 1 else 0 end as mostrecent
from table a
left join (
    select PersonId, max(CreatedAt) as CreatedAt
    from table
    group by PersonId
) b on a.CreatedAt = b.CreatedAt
    and a.PersonId = b.PersonId
```

Comment: I tested your answer and works pretty good but im using mysql 5.7 :/ Added this missing info to my question.

Comment: @WilliamMartins see updated asnwer then